# postgresql delete role with similar names

Tags: postgresql, roles, postgresql-9.2, psql

I have created roles with similar names like abc_ where number varies but abc_ always stays same. I can see the roles with following query

```
select * from pg_roles where rolname like 'abc_%';
```

But I don't know how to drop all role with similar name. I have got following query but it takes full name.

```
DROP ROLE name;
```

I am trying to dropping from psql and I am not writing any functions. Is there any query to to drop roles where I can have like 'abc_%'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using dynamic SQL of some sort, no, you can't do that. A simple example using dynamic SQL to drop the roles:

```
select 'DROP ROLE ' || rolname || ';' from pg_roles where rolname like 'abc_%';
```

If you are unwilling to paste the results into a psql session, you can also pipe it from one session to another.

```
psql -d yourdb -U youruser -qtAc "select 'DROP ROLE ' || rolname || ';' from pg_roles where rolname like 'abc_%'" | psql -d yourdb -U youruser
```